# How to get jQuery to treat elements individually?

Tags: jquery

In the following code I create ten elements and pass them all to jQuery code to get functionality. However, when I click on one, the click event fires for all of them. How do I have to change this code so that when I click on one of them, it only fires the event in that element?

**html/php:**

```
<?php
    for ($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++) {
        $r .= '<div class="testItem"><span class="title">title1</span><span class="message"/></div>';
    }
?>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        TESTITEM.initialize($('.testItem'));
    });
</script>
```

**javascript:**

```
var TESTITEM = TESTITEM || {};

TESTITEM.initialize = function(elemTest) {
    var elemTitle;

    this.defineVariables = function() {
        elemTitle = elemTest.find('.title');
        elemMessage = elemTest.find('.message');
    }

    this.functionalizeElements = function() {
        elemTitle.click(function(e) {
           elemMessage.html('done'); 
        });
    }

    this.decorateElements = function() {
        elemTitle.css('color','brown');
    }

    this.defineVariables();
    this.decorateElements();
    this.functionalizeElements();
}
```

### ADDENDUM:

When I change it to this, and I click on any element, only the last element shows the text:

```
$('.testItem').each(function(){
    TESTITEM.initialize($(this));
})
```

Comment: Don't call initialize function inside this write direct code in this will help you

Comment: What do you mean actually? I need to call initialize() or some method since I don't have a constructor in JavaScript objects as I do in other languages.

Comment: check softsdev created link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use each function of jquery and inside this use **$(this)**

```
$('.testItem').each(function(){
   $(this).find('.title').click(function(e) {
       $(this).parents('.testItem').find('.message').html('done');
        $(this).css('color','brown');
    });
})
```

**$('.testItem').each** will get all selector having **testItem** Class

and

using **$(this)** you can select individually selector so action will not affected to other element having class **testItem**

@@@@@  [See Example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jXwaq/)

Comment: I think This is short method to solve this problem
@Edward Tanguay you can also use this method

Comment: I tried this (see post above) but now when I click on any element, it shows only the text for the last element.

Comment: i think same you want as like softsdev made example

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the answer already provided would be to defer the resolution of `elemMessage` until the click event itself; inside the click handler, `this` will be the `elemTitle` clicked.

```
this.functionalizeElements = function() {
    elemTitle.click(function(e) {
       $(this).closest('.testItem').find('.message').html('done'); 
    });
}
```

This is because both `elemTitle` and `elemMessage` are jQuery objects of all instances of `.message` and `.title` on the page; calling `elemMessage.html('done')` in the click handler (as you've seen) sets the HTML of all of those elements.